# PHP OpenSSL - openssl_private_encrypt crashes webpage

Tags: php, openssl, xampp, public-key-encryption, phpseclib

This has been reported at [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55470&edit=1). If I replace **libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll** in `xampp/apache/bin` with the same files in `xampp/php/` then it works but I **CANNOT use SSL**

I need to use SSL, has anyone been able to resolve this?

---

I am using **OpenSSL** library in **PHP**(5.4.7) on **XAMPP**(1.8.1) for encryption, decryption, etc. I am also using SSL on localhost.

I am able to create the private-public key pair using `openssl_pkey_new()` method and generate the certificate as well.

But when I try to access my root certificate (create using the above function) the **webpage crashes**:

```
$root_private_key = openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents($path), $pass);
echo "KEY: " . $root_private_key; // KEY: Resource id #11
openssl_private_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted_data, $root_private_key);
```

I even tried using **phpseclib library** but that also does the same thing.

I have also tried to set `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

---

I checked **PHP log** and it is empty and found the following in **Apache logs**:

```
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3312:tid 484] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[ssl:warn] [pid 3312:tid 484] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3312:tid 484] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3312:tid 484] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[core:notice] [pid 3312:tid 484] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3312:tid 484] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1520
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:19
[ssl:warn] [pid 1520:tid 496] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1520:tid 496] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

---

I have tried following but none of that helps:

[PHP openssl_public_encrypt causing Page Timeout/Connection Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423799/php-openssl-public-encrypt-causing-page-timeout-connection-reset)

[php/timeout/connection to server reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610420/php-timeout-connection-to-server-reset?rq=1)

[Apache server (xampp) crashes when using openssl function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603960/apache-server-xampp-crashes-when-using-openssl-function)

[PHP dies unexpectedly without error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409439/php-dies-unexpectedly-without-error?rq=1)

I would appreciate any help/suggestion.

Comment: Where exactly it crashes?

Comment: If I don't use `openssl_private_encrypt()` method then it runs fine.

Comment: It seems like that it is failed to get the private key.

Comment: I read private key from file and output of `echo $root_private_key;` is `Resource ID #`

Comment: Please print the resource ID.

Comment: The output is: `Resource id #11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported at [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55470&edit=3). If I replace the following files in **xampp/apache/bin** with the same files in **xampp/php/** then it works:

- **libeay32.dll**
- **ssleay32.dll**

BUT, **SSL cannot be used** otherwise Apache gives error when starting up.

Comment: Is there a solution to this that fixes the problem but doesn't force me to disable SSL? I need both.

Comment: @nathanjosiah Sorry, I couldn't find any solution. The only way I could make it work was by disabling SSL.

Comment: Hi, I solved my problem copying libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from the PHP folder to my Apache bin, like 'ska-pig' answered in php.net

Answer (score 2):

For those of you still having trouble:

Until a fully packaged official build of xampp is released with the next version of apache which should fix this bug, I have successfully fixed this issue by changing my version of Apache to one found here: http://www.apachelounge.com/download/ This fixes the bug but still allows me to use OpenSSL

The second Apache 2.2.4 download on this page was built specifically to fix this bug. For me it was easy as:

- Stopping Apache
- Renaming `xampp\apache` to `xampp\apacheold` just in case it broke.
- Copied in the `Apache24` to `xampp\Apache24` from the downloaded zip
- Renamed it to `apache`
- Copied the `.bat` files from the `xampp\apacheold` folder into the new `xampp\apache` folder.
- Replaced the `xampp\apache\conf` folder with the one from `xampp\apacheold`
- Start Apache again

I Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: In addition to your steps, I had to copy the libraries ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll from "xampp \ php" and paste in "xampp \ apache \ bin". It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

phpseclib uses OpenSSL, if available, for RSA private key generation. To disable this behavior do this after Crypt/RSA.php has been included:

```
define('CRYPT_RSA_MODE', CRYPT_RSA_MODE_INTERNAL);
```

How big, btw, is the key you're trying to generate?

Answer (score 0):

From my side I had:

- IIS on Windows 11
- PHP 7.0
- libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll v1.0.2.8

I found the 2 dlls somewhere in visual studio in the simulator with version 1.0.2.19, I have replaced them both and it started working. It was for the function openssl_pkcs7_sign where it was crashing all the time.

Hope this helps.